# How not to Release a View in Xcode

Tags: view, xcode4.2, release, nstimer

Hello I have a stopwatch view and when the user clicks on the back button to go to another view the stopwatch will stop.  I had people tell me that is because it is being released.

I want the stop watch to keep running.

So how do I un-release or not allow it to be released?

Here i my code.

.h

```
UILabel *stopWatchLabel;

NSTimer *stopWatchTimer; // Store the timer that fires after a certain time
NSDate *startDate; // Stores the date of the click on the start button

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *stopWatchLabel;

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setStopWatchLabel:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)updateTimer
{
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
startDate = [NSDate date];

// Create the stop watch timer that fires every 10 ms
stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
[stopWatchTimer invalidate];
stopWatchTimer = nil;
[self updateTimer]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different approach, than to change the view controller's behavior:

You can make the timer independent from the view controller by moving the timer functionality into a separate object. That way the timer object has a different life cycle than the view controller object. For example, you can create (and release) the timer object in the application delegate, and create a reference to it and access it in your view controller.